# handlebar binding not working on parent template when navigating directly to child template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

Dashboard template:

```
<div id="main-container" class="container bgNotFaded" {{bind-attr class="faded:bgFaded"}}>
```

Dashboard controller:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   ...
   faded: false,
   ...
})
```

`faded` is the property I'm having trouble with.

Steps:
Navigate to --> `www.example.com/dashboard`
Then navigate through link to --> `www.example.com/dashboard/account`.
--- At this point everything works, my background fades and `faded` is set to true ---
Next I refresh page `www.example.com/dashboard/account`
--- And it's broke, the background isn't faded even though the `accountRoute` is loaded---

My `accountRoute`:

```
export default Authenticated.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render({
            into: 'dashboard',
            outlet: 'modal'
        });
    },
    setupController: function(controller){
        var dashController = this.controllerFor('dashboard');
        dashController.set('faded', true);
        ....
    },
    ...
)};
```

My router is setup like this:

```
this.resource('dashboard', {path: '/'}, function() {
    ...
    this.resource('account', {path: '/account'}, function() {
```

So I know the dashboard template is being loaded. In fact if I open the ember inspector I can see on my `dashboardController` that the property `faded == true` but the class `bgFaded` isn't in my rendered template.

**Question** Why when I navigate to the child route directly is the handlebar binding in my parent template not working?

Thanks.

Comment: My initial guess would be that when you refresh the page the `faded`'s state is being reset. Is it possible to provide a jsbin example?

Comment: @JDillon522 `faded's` state is being reset. I can follow that in chrome by setting a breakpoint. So when page initially loads `faded` is false but when it hits the `setupController` of `account` `faded` is set to true. So `faded` is being set to true, but for some reason that's not adding the class `bgFaded` to my template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some issues when defining a class attribute on an element in addition to using `bind-attr`. Give this a shot?

```
<div id="main-container" {{bind-attr class=":container :bgNotFaded faded:bgFaded"}}>
```

Comment: ha, that totally worked. I didn't even look at that being an issue. Thanks man.